# progress bar issue while export to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, progress-bar

i am getting an issue with the progress bar while using it with generating excel report...

what exactly i am trying to acheive is :- I trying to generate an excel report on click of a button and as the report generation takes a lot of time i want a progress bar until the excel is generated

**PROBLEM** :- the progress bar shows up when the button is clicked but **it doesnt hides/disables after the excel download is prompt to the user**. The progress bar is still there...

I am using a postback trigger button in update panel to generate excel. And using Response.Write() method to generate the excel report.

And i am using pagerequestmanager to register the postback start and finish handlers.
Please help me i am stuck at this...

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    //Raised before processing of an asynchronous postback starts and the postback request is sent to the server.
    prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    // Raised after an asynchronous postback is finished and control has been returned to the browser.
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //Shows the modal popup - the update progress
        var popup = $find('<%= modalPopup.ClientID %>');
        if (popup != null) {
            popup.show();
        }
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        //Hide the modal popup - the update progress
        var popup = $find('<%= modalPopup.ClientID %>');
        if (popup != null) {
            popup.hide();
        }
    }
    function ShowProgress() {
        var myExtender = $find('<%= modalPopup.ClientID %>');

        myExtender.show();
        return true;
    }
</script>
<div>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updateProg" runat="server">
<ProgressTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="imgProg" ImageUrl="ajax-loader.gif" runat="server" />
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="updateProg" PopupControlID="updateProg" BackgroundCssClass="modalPopup" />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlData" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Excel" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" OnClientClick="return ShowProgress(); return false;"/>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
        </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

And in the button click i am using the foolowing code :-

```
try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(7000);
                Response.Clear();
                String Attachment = "attachment; filename=" + "MonitoringReport.xls";
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", Attachment);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.Write("<table border=1 style='font-size:12px;'>");
                Response.Write("<th>" + "Col1" + "</th>");
                Response.Write("<th>" + "Col2" + "</th>");
                Response.Write("<th>" + "Col3" + "</th>");
                Response.Write("<th>" + "Col4" + "</th>");
                Response.Write("</table>");
                Response.End();
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException ex)
            {
            }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question will be difficult to answer in its current form, without knowing how you used the methods you described. It would greatly help if you would define the language you are programming in and supply some code as an example.

Comment: have updated the post please check...